# Cannot save keys to SSH Shell

Tags: ssh

I'm new to programming. I'm learning how to use Github.

I'm following https://youtu.be/RGOj5yH7evk tutorial on how to use Github. I'm at the 25 min mark.

I'm connecting my computer to Github. I'm in the terminal and type:

```
workspace@Gurinderss-iMac ~ % vim ~/.ssh/config
```

I'm in a place where I paste the following:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Problem is I can't save this file. I've tried to open up another terminal and used this command:

```
ssh-add -D
```

It's from here: [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-ssh-setting-up-ssh-keys/#:~:text=Create%20a%20New%20SSH%20Key%20Pair&text=Enter%20file%20in%20which%20to,ssh%20directory](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-ssh-setting-up-ssh-keys/#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20New%20SSH%20Key%20Pair&text=Enter%20file%20in%20which%20to,ssh%20directory).

Comment: > "I can't save this file" is there any error? please show us.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you did generate an ed25519 private key when you write `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`: the tutorial also speak of the classic ras key (`id_rsa`)

> Problem is I can't save this file

Simply try with another editor, or check first if there is any right issue (`chmod`) which would prevent you to save it:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ls -alrth
```

If you see a permission [like 400](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-400/) on the file, you would be able to read it only, not modify it.